# import numbers into mysql from text file where comma is used as decimal separator

Tags: mysql, replace

I want to load data into mysql but the available datas are in a format like

```
37,85
36,41
38,21
38,44
```

Is there a way to replace the comma into a dot while importing these datas 
otherwise mysql only shows

```
 37
 36
 38
 38
```

Comment: Is this decimal comma/decimal dot? Or just formatting?

Comment: I am loading the data with: load data local infile 'path.csv' into table etf fields terminated by '\n'

Comment: The easiest way is probably to do a search and replace on the file you're importing from. A regular expression like `([0-9]+),([0-9]+)` into `\1.\2` would do fine, unless the file has other instances of numbers separated by commas that you don't want to convert.

Answer (score 7):

You can assign the values to variables and manipulate them on the way in. Something like this should work.

`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'path.csv' INTO TABLE etf (@numcol) FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\n' SET mycol = REPLACE(@numcol, ',', '.')`