# Convert String or Float to Int when Importing a CSV into MySQL

Tags: mysql, csv, data-conversion

I need to import Data from a CSV-File into MySQL/MariaDB. Here is an example of the data:

```csv
01.01.2021 00:15;0,000000;W;123,000000;W;9,000000;W;0,000000;W;9,000000;W
01.01.2021 00:30;0,000000;W;126,000000;W;9,000000;W;0,000000;W;9,000000;W
01.01.2021 00:45;0,000000;W;119,000000;W;6,000000;W;0,000000;W;6,000000;W
```

I want to use Fields Nr. 1, 4, 6. The Date in the first column needs to be converted into SQL datetime. I managed all of that. But I am stuck when converting the 4th and 6th value into an Int (or an Float if some one will add decimals to the measurement).

My current code which works fine is:

```sql
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/eam_energy.csv' 
INTO TABLE  grafana.elec_eam_delivered 
FIELDS OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
TERMINATED BY ';' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
IGNORE 18 ROWS 
(@datetime, @dummy, @dummy, active_power, @dummy, reactive_power, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy) 
SET datetime = STR_TO_DATE(@datetime, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i');
```

`active_power` and `reactive_power` are integers in the schema. When importing the values are cut at the ',' (which is the German decimal delimiter). But I get a warning in `SHOW WARNINGS`:

> Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'reactive_power' at row 32

I want the import to work without any warnings. How can I convert the `123,000000` into either `123` or `123.000000` ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [import numbers into mysql from text file where comma is used as decimal separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487350/import-numbers-into-mysql-from-text-file-where-comma-is-used-as-decimal-separato)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do the conversion direct by the import like this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/eam_energy.csv' 
INTO TABLE  grafana.elec_eam_delivered 
FIELDS OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
TERMINATED BY ';' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
IGNORE 18 ROWS 
(@datetime, @dummy, @dummy, @active_power, @dummy, @reactive_power, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy) 
SET DATETIME = STR_TO_DATE(@datetime, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i'),
active_power = SUBSTRING_INDEX(@active_power,',',1),
reactive_power = SUBSTRING_INDEX(@reactive_power,',',1);
```

Comment: Great! That was exactly what I was looking for. There is a small syntax error in your answer: The multipe `SET` have to be separated by `,`:

```(@datetime, @dummy, @dummy, @active_power, @dummy, @reactive_power, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy) 
SET DATETIME = STR_TO_DATE(@datetime, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i'),
active_power = SUBSTRING_INDEX(@active_power,',',1),
reactive_power = SUBSTRING_INDEX(@reactive_power,',',1);
```

Comment: @Matze Q - thx - i have change my answer

Comment: Please change your answer again :) there should be no `SET` before the second and third occurrence of the commands. One `SET` and then all commands separated by comma. Never the less is your answer working great!

Comment: done :-) , OMG its not my day

Answer (score 0):

Change the schema for `reactive_power` and `active_power` to `VARCHAR(255)` and import your file. Then replace ',' with '.':

```
UPDATE
  grafana.elec_eam_delivered
SET
   reactive_power = REPLACE(reactive_power, ',', '.'),
   active_power = REPLACE(active_power, ',', '.')
```

Then change the schema for `active_power` and `reactive_power` to `INT` or `FLOAT` (your choice).